# How to display monthwise report in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have created 6 months data in my database which is having column name as productiondate. i have provided 6 months date for this productiondate column. Right now i need to retrieve data for monthwise data from this single productiondate column.

I need to display in the following manner

jan , feb, mar,........dec in seperate columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide any details on your current table structure or existing query, but it sounds like you are trying to *pivot* data from rows into columns.

MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will need to replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.  You code would be similar to this:

```
select otherColumns, 
  max(case when month(productiondate)=1 then value end) Jan,
  max(case when month(productiondate)=2 then value end) Feb,
  max(case when month(productiondate)=3 then value end) Mar,
  max(case when month(productiondate)=4 then value end) Apr,
  max(case when month(productiondate)=5 then value end) May,
  max(case when month(productiondate)=6 then value end) Jun,
  ....
from yourtable
group by otherColumns
```

You would then replace `otherColumns` with any other columns that you want included in your final result. These columns would then be included in the `GROUP BY`.  Also you would replace the `value` with the name of the column that you want displayed under each month.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `GROUP BY` month and generate month wise report, You may also need to use Aggregate functions like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG` based on your requirements.

You can utilize `MonthName` function to get Month Name from date
e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT MONTHNAME('1998-02-05');
    -> 'February'
```

so your query might look like below:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(productiondate) as mon, SUM(XYZ), COUNT(*) 
FROM Your_Table_Name
GROUP BY mon
```